# remove repeated character between words

Tags: regex

I am trying out the quiz from [Regex 101](http://www.regex101.com/quiz/)

In Task 6, the question is

> Oh no! It seems my friends spilled beer all over my keyboard last night and my keys are super sticky now. Some of the time when I press a key, I get two duplicates. Can you p**pp**l**ll**ea**aa**se**ee** help me fix this? Content in bold should be removed.

I have tried [this regex](http://www.regex101.com/r/lL7jV4)

```
([a-z])(\1{2})
```

But couldn't get the solution.

Comment: Taken literally, "characters repeated more than twice" means that `ppp` would still be ok because `p` is repeated exactly twice...

Comment: @om39a what version of regex is used on that quiz?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution for the riddle on that website is:

```
/(.)\1{2}/g
```

Since any key on the keyboard can get stuck, so we need to use `.`.

`\1` in the regex means match whatever the **1**st capturing group `(.)` matches.

Replacement is `$1` or `\1`.

The rest of your regex is correct, just that there are unnecessary capturing groups.

Comment: @nhahtdh what does the \1 mean?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is correct if you want to match exactly three characters. If you want to match at least three, that is

```
([a-z])(\1{2,})
```

or

```
([a-z])(\1\1+)
```

Since you don't need to capture anything but the first occurence, these are slightly better:

```
([a-z])\1{2}   # your original regex (exactly three occurences)
([a-z])\1{2,}
([a-z])\1\1+
```

Now, the replacement should be exactly one occurence of the character, and nothing more:

```
\1
```

Comment: I just edited the question with the exact problem statement. According to the problem statement, a key can produce 1 or 3 characters, and the question asks to replace 3 instances of the repetition to 1.

Comment: Too many capturing groups, what you need to capture is only the first character.

Comment: @nhahtdh removed the "which you don't" part.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
(.)\1+
```

with:

```
\1
```

This of course requires that your regex engine suports backreferences... Also, in the replacement part, and according to regex engines, `\1` may have to be written as `$1`.

Comment: But insted of + we should have used {2} as per the question and explained by nhahtdh

Comment: To be honest I didn't look at the exact question (site requires JavaScript and login etc), so if exactly two tokens are required beyong the first one then yes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with `(\w)(\1+)?` but can't find out how to "remove" within the given site...

Best way would be to replace the results of the secound match with empty strings